# Camera calibration with circular pattern

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera-calibration

I'm following [this tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#calibration) to calibrate my camera (with some lens) on Raspberry Pi, but using a [circular pattern](http://nerian.com/support/resources/patterns/) instead of the chessboard one. The problem is that the resulting undistorted image is shrinked and not full, and when I get every shrinking away from the code, it looks like the right part of [image: this] (usually it's even worse). The question is if it is possible to do something with the code so that it would give away a picture like [the example from the tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/calib_result.jpg). Do I have to use the chessboard pattern for this?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time



# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
#objp = np.zeros((4*11,3), np.float32)
#objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
objp=np.array([[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[2,0,0],[3,0,0],[0.5,0.5,0],[1.5,0.5,0],[2.5,0.5,0],[3.5,0.5,0]])
for y in range(2,11):
        for x in range(4):
                objp=np.append(objp,[np.array([objp[4*(y-2)+x][0],objp[4*(y-2)+x][1]+1,0])],axis=0)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

#images = glob.glob('pict*.jpg')

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)
ret0=[]
j=0
for i,frame in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True)):
    image = frame.array
    img=image[::-1]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray, (4,11),None,flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True and np.sum(np.int32(ret0))<15 and not i%10:
        ret0.append(ret)
        print("{} more for proper calibration".format(15-np.sum(np.int32(ret0))))
        objpoints.append(objp.astype('float32'))

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2.reshape(-1, 2).astype('float32'))

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img.copy(), (4,11), corners2,ret)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        cv2.imwrite('cal{}.jpg'.format(j),img)
        j+=1
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
    elif np.sum(np.int32(ret0))<15:
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
    else:
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        break

dist = np.array([-0.13615181, 0.53005398, 0, 0, 0]) # no translation
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))

np.savetxt('newcameramtx.out',newcameramtx)
np.savetxt('mtx.out',mtx)
np.savetxt('dist.out',dist)

#img=cv2.imread('pict1.jpg')
# undistort
dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

# crop the image
x,y,w,h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('calibresult.png',dst)

cv2.imshow('undistorted',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)&0xFF

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

UPD: I've tried calibration with the chessboard pattern, and the program didn't even want to recognize the pattern! Here are examples
with detected circular pattern:  [image: one] [image: other]
[image: one more] [image]

So the program allegedly detects the circles, but not as ideally, as it would be wanted.

Comment: I've used  the chessboard  to calibrate it work pretty good, the  problem you have with your circular pattern is  that you need to define a radius while using the intersections are pretty well define so the algorithm can search for a black white change in 4 directions (2 black & 2 white  squares ) , so I guess it would work better . PS : did this using C++ & don't have a clew how to this in python so sorry can't help you with the code !

Comment: You trying to calculate the subpixel position of your circle center positions with `cv2.cornerSubPix`, but you have no corners so this may lead to problems. And why not using a checkerboard? It is invariant against bias distortion. Are your detected center positions right or absolutly wrong? Can you post an image of the drawn "corners" ;)

Comment: @PSchn, updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to tune the parameters of the blob detector. By the default the `findCirclesGrid` uses the SimpleBlobDetector. So try to adust the parameters, for example:

```
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.minArea = 10;
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 5;
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
```

and then pass it to findCirclesGrid:

```
cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray, (4,11),None,flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID,detector)
```

Additionaly you can try to use `cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID + cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING`

For more information about the SimpleBlobDetector and its parameters see [this tutrial](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/).

Comment: Do I have to change the `cv2.cornerSubPix` to something else, or, maybe, even delete this line and everything related to it at all?

Comment: if you want to use just a circle pattern, you can delete this line.

Comment: OK, so it worked, when I wrote down `ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray, (4,11),None,flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID,blobDetector=detector)`. When I used the resulted matrices in another program, it shouted that the lines with `x,y,w,h = roi; frame = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]` cropped the whole frame and because of that the function `cv2.imwrite()` couldn't write anything, but when I comment these lines, everything is okay (at least I hope that it is). So, thanks